# BlobServiceClient cannot connect by connection string, Buffer is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, azure-blob-storage

i want to use storage account in my react webpage. For that i am using `BlobServiceClient`.

When i am using SAS connection string

```
const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString("BlobEndpoint=...")
```

Everything works fine but when i want to switch for storage account connection string:

```
const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;...")
```

my page stuck. My question is, why i can not use standard connection string in `BlobServiceClient`?

EDIT:

Error from console:

```
utils.common.ts:184 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at extractConnectionStringParts (utils.common.ts:184:22)
    at Function.fromConnectionString (BlobServiceClient.ts:386:28)
    at Component._fetchContainer (Component.tsx:107:53)
    at Component.componentDidMount (Component.tsx:46:20)
    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:20663:24)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:23426:7)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:3945:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:31)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:23151:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are running into this error is because you are trying to connect to your Storage account from a JavaScript app (and not a Node app). Account connection string based connections are only allowed for Node apps.

From the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobserviceclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blobserviceclient-fromconnectionstring):

> Account connection string or a SAS connection string of an Azure
> storage account. [ **Note - Account connection string can only be used
> in NODE.JS runtime.** ]

Comment: Okay, thanks, but im running my app in docker and i am using command `npm config set "strict-ssl" false -g && yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g && yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production=false && yarn start` for starting it.  I am not a frontend dev but is it not node js runtime? Frontend is written in REactJS

Comment: Is your code is running in Frontend (in your React App) or Backend (some API using Node)?

Comment: it is running in frontend

Comment: Yeah, then you can't use the full account connection string. You will need to use a SAS Token based connection string.

Comment: Gracias, there is a workaround to use connection string?

Comment: You can't use full account connection string from the frontend app. This is done for the security reason - anybody can look at your JS code and get the account connection string. 2 options - 1) Use SAS based connection string (which you know works) and 2) Use Azure AD based connection.

Comment: I hav a proxy server on top of every api call

Comment: `I hav a proxy server on top of every api call ` - I am not sure what that means but if you really have to use account connection string, you will need to move the code to interact with Blob Storage to your backend code.